# What causes 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Connection' and how do I fix it?

Tags: mysql, scala

I have a Scala application connected to my SQL database but it gives me the error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Connection

I have run Scala applications connected to a SQL DB before, but now it's not working all of a sudden. What causes this and how should I go about fixing it?

[image]

Comment: Try to compile and run from `Project1` root directory, not from `src\main\scala`. Where does your  `Connection` class live? Ideally just create a simple SBT project that will set the environment correctly.

Comment: if you post directory structure and files used, maybe JAVA_HOME it will be easier to know.

Answer (score 0):

java.sql.Connection is part of the java runtime.

The vm is not able to load that class.

This could happen when the operation-system does not allow the user "dauld" to read that file.

Also possible is a Classloader that did not inherit from System-Classloaders, so the runtime jars might be readable but a ClassLoader explicitly avoid those runtime-jars.